# field has incomplete type C++

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to make class that has a member of type of it's enclosing class but I get an error saying field has incomplete type. here is an example

```
class List {
public:
        List (int element, List rest) {
                 _first = element;
                 _rest = rest;
         }
.
.
.
}
```

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: How is `_rest` declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

`'rest'` should be a pointer to a `List`.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't given us the complete definition of `List`, but I'm guessing from your description that you have something like:

```
class List
{
    ...
    List _rest;
};
```

Obviously, this is impossible.  An object cannot contain a member of its own type, as this would lead to an infinite recursion!

Perhaps you want a member that is a pointer or a reference?

Comment: Well, I don't know how 'obvious' it is, it's not like it's an impossible task and plenty of languages with multi-pass compilers allow such a thing.

Comment: @Ed - It has nothing to do with multi pass, but how you store the data. What would the size be of a list with an inner list with an inner list with an inner...

Comment: @Bo Persson: You're right, it doesn't have anything to do with multi-pass, which is why the member must obviously (as pointed out) be a pointer.  I thought I deleted that comment...